# prevent api call from execution repeatedly in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am making a api call from a directive. There is a condition to show directive. I am handling it using ng-show. But when first time html loads api call is executed even if ng-show flag is false.

I want to make api call only at first time when ng-show flag is true. After change in this ng-show flag i do not want to make api call.

I have done something like this.

```js
angular.module("module").directive("customDirective", function(){
  return {
    templateUrl : "cutomTemplate.html",
    replace : true,
    scope : {},
    link : {
        apicall();
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<custom-directive ng-show="value === 1"></custom-directive>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution i came up. This involves registering a watch on ngShow attribute in your directive scope and then de registering it once api call is made. See my fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/cmyworld/u57dw8ws/

The directive now looks like:

```
angular.module("module").directive("customDirective", function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            ngShow: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            var observeFn = scope.$watch('ngShow', function (value) {
                if (value) {
                    console.log('Making api call');
                    observeFn(); // degister after first callback,    
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

`ng-if` may not work, if you show hide the element again and again.